# Image not displayed in IE 11 and MS-EDGE

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a web page, the problem is that IE and MS-Edge doesn't seem to load some images. Hence I tried working on just one image, given below. This also doesn't get displayed. Everything works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. Could you please tell me what the problem is??

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHa0h.png)

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <img src="./images/services/2.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88bpb0hu/1/)

Comment: Please could you provide jsfiddle of your code

Comment: check your image extension,maybe it is png not jpg

Comment: It was .jpg itself, but I noticed the extension being changed once I upload it online. I then converted the image to .PNG. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you double check the path of the image. Maybe it helps if you drag 'n drop the image directly to IE or Edge and have a look at the address displayed in the browser...

Comment: Did so! even that doesn't get displayed!

Comment: Is it the answer to the question? Please write in the comments first . People look for the answers , not considerations.